# Garage door won’t open unless I hold button down

Tags: doors, garage

If I hook 2 wires together that go to the sensors can I bypass the sensors?

Comment: Adding the make and model of the opener will help, as well as other details.  Currently your question is too broad and will only get you guesses.

Comment: No, you can't bypass the sensors on modern units. Nor should you.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately (and because the makers and their insurance companies don't like getting sued for killing people) garage door sensor circuits are a bit more subtle than that.

Fix it properly or operate the door manually.